# Difference between objects and data structures?

Tags: java, design, object-oriented

So I was reading https://hackernoon.com/objects-vs-data-structures-e380b962c1d2

and I stumbled upon this quote :

"A Person data structure has a first name, last name, and phone number. A Person object walks, runs, jumps, and speaks. A Person object does things."

As I understand, the Person data structure would be like :

```java
public class Person
{
    public String name;
    public int weight;
}
```

Now for the Person object that "walks, runs, jumps, and speaks." I'm confused how this would be any different than the previous class with just added methods like so :

```java
public class Person
{
    public String name;
    public int weight;

    public void run(){
        stuff 
    }

    public void jump(){
         stuff
    }
}
```

Sorry, I'm just confused and any clarification would be extremely helpful!

Comment: Make name and weight private in the second example. A data structure has no behavior and exposes its state, an object encapsulates it’s data (hides its state) and exposes behavior.

Comment: The article you've linked is wrong - It states that `Person` is "not an object"  based on the fact that it has no behaviour.  This statement is completely incorrect -- an 'object' is just *'a thing which exists in memory'*. There is no requirement for an object to have behaviour, and indeed a data structure ***is*** an object because it exists in memory, it just happens to have no behaviour. It's useful of course to distinguish between objects which have behaviour and those which don't, but the concept of an "object" is general, and certainly not limited to the narrow definition provided here.

Comment: It’s unfortunate that we don’t have a word to describe an object with behavior. Therefor, in pure OO-paradigm semantics, a thing is not an object if it doesn’t have behavior, it’s a data structure. In a more general context, every instance of a class is an object, regardless of behavior.

Comment: @RikD indeed, however I think the overloaded terminology is ultimately the source of confusion. "object" seems to be frequently redefined within sub-contexts of computer science, despite already having a generally-accepted (albeit very broad) definition.   I find it unhelpful when the meanings of words are redefined in this way because I think it creates barriers to communication, which in-turn creates barriers to learning - such as in this example, where the useful concept of distinguishing "data objects" vs "behavioural objects" seems to have been lost in the ambiguity of the term "object".

Comment: what makes you think they need to be different?

Comment: The book Clean Code mentions that having objects that have behavior and has data is considered a hybrid between data structures and objects and that having such hybrids is bad practice. However, I see many objects defined such as 


```java
public class Person
{
    private String name;
    private int weight;

    public void run(){
        stuff 
    }

    public void jump(){
         stuff
    }

    public get/set name/weight ...
}
```

Is this truly bad practice? Why would I want a Person who can run and jump but cannot change his/her name/weight?

Answer (score 0):

There is an important difference between Abstract Data Types (which is what all the examples in the beginning of the article are) and Objects (which is what all the examples at the end of the article are), and that is the way that *Data Abstraction* is performed.

In Object-Oriented Programming, the mechanism for Data Abstraction is (not surprisingly) Object-Oriented Data Abstraction. This essentially refers to the *Message Protocol*, the internal representation of an object is hidden behind the Behavioral Interface (aka Protocol) formed by the Messages it understands and how it responds to those Messages. In Object-Oriented Abstraction, the Abstraction is formed by a *Behavioral Interface*.

With Abstract Data Types, the Abstraction is formed by the *Type System*.

One of the major differences between Object-Oriented Data Abstraction and Abstract Data Types is that two instances of the same Abstract Data Types have access to each other's internal representation, whereas an Object can *never* access another Object's internal representation *even if they are of the same type*.

A great explanation of this difference is given in [*On Understanding Data Abstraction, Revisited*](http://CS.UTexas.Edu/~wcook/Drafts/2009/essay.pdf) by [William R. Cook](http://WCook.BlogSpot.Com/), which is *very* approachable.

In particular, in Java, *classes* define Abstract Data Types, *interfaces* define Objects.

Comment: The book Clean Code mentions that having objects that have behavior and has data is considered a hybrid between data structures and objects and that having such hybrids is bad practice. However, I see many objects defined such as 

```java
java public class Person { 
private String name; private int weight; public void run(){ stuff } public void jump(){ stuff } public get/set name/weight ... }
``` Is this truly bad practice? Why would I want a Person who can run and jump but cannot change his/her name/weight?